# Cab vs Taxi UK usage

Tags: word-usage

Is “cab company” or taxi company” more common in the UK?  Or do they mean different things?

Comment: ... or even a *taxi cab company*.

Comment: I'd have said 'taxi firm'. But that's not supported by [these Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=taxi+firm%2Ctaxi+company%2Ccab+firm%2Ccab+company&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ctaxi%20firm%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctaxi%20company%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccab%20firm%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccab%20company%3B%2Cc0). / They're just alternative names.

Comment: I'd say "taxi company" (or, indeed "firm", like @Edwin). I think "taxi" is the more common term in the UK, but most people will understand "cab". There is a distinction between a "taxi" and a ["black cab"](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/black-cab), though.

Comment: @Pam Once you get into legal terminology, it becomes more complicated. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taxicabs_of_the_United_Kingdom#Elsewhere) has: [In other places] there are two types of "taxi"— _hackney carriages_ (licensed under the Town Police Clauses Act 1847), which may pick up fares on the street or be pre-booked and have a meter that charges a rate set by the local authority (alternatively the driver may negotiate a lower fare ...

Comment: with the customer), and _private hire vehicles_ (licensed under the Local Government (Miscellaneous Provisions) Act 1976) which must be pre-booked and whose rates are set by the private hire operator.' [italicisation mine]

Answer (score -1):

From looking at the [Glasgow Phone Book online](https://www.thephonebook.bt.com/Business/TypeSearch/?BusinessSearchTerm=Taxis%20and%20Private%20Hire%20Vehicles&Location=Glasgow&BusinessTypeFound=true&LocationFound=True&PageNumber=1), the word that is **not** used in the title of firms is **Company**. If anything is used, it is **Ltd**.

The following are found:

- X (± Radio) Cars: 18
- X Cabs (± Ltd): 4
- X Private Hire: 11
- X Taxis (± Ltd): 11

So, on the basis of this limited survey, *Taxis is more common than Cabs*.

However, the new word, I believe, is `Uber`.

Comment: -1? What’s not to like?